# Mass link redirection script

Tags: redirect

Good Day Everyone,

My website uses a datafeed to upload product listings on my website and the links point to different external websites. I have two options. Either I simply use the links to external websites. Or use some script so that my website link appears first followed by the external link like this:

```
http://www.mysite/redirect.php?id=http://extsite.com/bla=1&bla=2&bla=3
```

When clicked, the external link should be executed and the visitor should be transferred to: `http://extsite.com/bla=1&bla=2&bla=3`

I am playing with php code that will goto the redirect.php file:

```
<?PHP
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  header("Location: $id");
  exit();
?>
```

The above method works if there are no parameters after the ext link. But if there are parameters (bla=1&bla=2&bla=3), it doesn't work. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend to encode the `http://extsite.com/bla=1&bla=2&bla=3
`

Comment: Book Of Zeus, thankyou for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `http://www.mysite/redirect.php?id=http://extsite.com/bla=1&bla=2&bla=3`

Well, that's wrong. Your script gets id=http://extsite.com/bla=1 and bla=2 and bla=3 as its three parameters. Whoever is generating the URL needs to URL-encode the extra & characters as %26.

Comment: Hello Joe, Thanks for replying to my question. So if I change all the & into %26, the script will work for sure? I will try your suggestion and will see if it helps. Once again, thankyou so much for your help.

Comment: OH MY GOD! I can't imagine I wasted 2 days for a simple mistake. That's what you get for being a programming noob! Joe, thank you so much for helping me out with this problem. And thank you so much StakOverflow for creating this great platform where programmers are so helpful! Love you guys!!

Comment: @SuzanOmar: Please remember to accept the answer that answered your question or led you to the answer.  This is how SO lives. ;)

Comment: Wow, it really took me time to find the "accept button". Spent 10 minutes looking for where the accept button could be but finally found it on the left. Newbie me!